# Azure Automatic Production Traffic Routing

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web App Service that has two Deployment Slots, the default slot for Production and one named "stage". Following Azure's docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots , I have been able to successfully route traffic to the "stage" slot manually by setting by setting the `?x-ms-routing-name=stage` parameter, which sets a cookie in the browser.

According to the Azure docs, when client traffic is automatically routed (i.e. 10% stage, 90% production) to the "stage" slot, the client is then "pinned" to that slot for the life of that client session. This means that the `x-ms-routing-name` cookie is set to "stage" for that client.

My question is: What happens when you want to fully swap the stage slot to the production slot and have no traffic routing to the "stage" slot? Do clients that have had their cookie set to "stage" now have to manually clear cookies in order to properly route to the "production" slot? In my application's environment, it is not ideal to require users to clear cookies or have them click a link that sets the cookie back to `x-ms-routing-name=self`. What happens for those users if the stage slot is deleted or turned off?